# An isomorphism of algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

In the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ define an operator by declaring 
$$\sigma\mapsto sign(\sigma)\sigma \hskip5mm (\sigma\in S_n)$$
and extend it linearly to $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$. This is clearly isomorphism of vector space $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ to itself.

It is an *algebra isomorphism?* If yes, is there specific name to it?

On the generators of the vector space, the product is obviously preserved by above map, so it seems that the map should be *algebra* homomorphism (hence isomorphism).

Comment: Yes this is an algebra isomorphism. To see this, write two generic elements in $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$; compute their product and look at what the coefficient of $\sigma$ is. Now using that $sign(g)=sign(g^{-1})$, show that applying the your map only multiplies this coefficient by $sign(\sigma)$.

Comment: I don't think it has a name, although this construction works for all 1-dimensional representation of a group G inducing an algebra homomorphism of k[G].

Comment: Signed representation or signed character.